# Shopify- getting attribute form <select>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am developing a store in Sopify and I have a custom section in which i have selector for choosing variants and I also have a variant image shown next to it. What I want to make is that when I choose a variant, the featured image also changes to the featured image of that selected variant, but i don't know how should I get it's attribute.

This is the code I have:

```js
  $('.upsell-variants__selector').click(function(){
    var main_img = $(this).attr('data-variant');
    $('.product__upsell-image img').attr('src', main_img);
  });
```

```html
              <div class="product__upsell-image">
                  <img src="{{ all_products[product_one].variants[0].featured_image.src | img_url: 'master' }}" data-src="" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="product__upsell-form">
                    
                
                  <form class="upsell__form" id="product-upsell" method="post" action="/cart/add" id="form--{{ upsell_prod1.id }}">
                    <!-- Variant selector -->
                    <select  calss="upsell-variants" name="id">
                      {% for variant in upsell_prod1.variants %}
                      <option class="upsell-variants__selector" data-src="{{variant.featured_image.src | img_url: 'master'}}" data-variant="{{ variant.id }}" value="{{ variant.id }}"
                              {% if variant == current_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
                              >
                        {{ variant.title }}{%comment%} - {{ variant.price | money }} {%endcomment%}{% if variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}- Sold Out{%endif%}
                      </option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <div class="product__upsell-price">{{ all_products[product_one].variants[1].price | money }}</div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn upsell-atc single-ajax-cart-btn-upsell" id="add-to-cart-button">Quick Add</button>
                  </form>
```

Comment: Try `var main_img = this.dataset.src;` (in general it's `$(this).attr('data-src')`, that's where the image url is I guess)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. I think that for some reason i can't even select options? I don't know...

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/wcxLkonb/2/ Just do some basic debugging: `console.log(this)` is a start

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't work for me. What am i doing wrong than? https://i.imgur.com/hXadWko.png

Comment: What, you mean my fiddle isn't working for you? Did you check the browser console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
  $('.upsell-variants').on('change', function() {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var main_img = $(optionSelected).data("src");
    $('.product__upsell-image img').attr('src', main_img);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle a change in a select element's value, you probably want to use the [$.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function here. It will attach an 'change' event handler to your select element - this way you could just put the URL in the value attribute.

```
// JS
$( ".upsell-variants" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      console.log("Variant selected!:", this.value);
      $('.product__upsell-image img').attr('src', this.attr('data-variant');
    })
  })

// HTML
// I fixed the spelling in "class" here
<select class="upsell-variants" name="id">
  {% for variant in upsell_prod1.variants %}
  <option class="upsell-variants__selector" data-src="{{variant.featured_image.src | img_url: 'master'}}" value="{{variant.id}}">
  {{ variant.title }}{%comment%} - {{ variant.price | money }} {%endcomment%}. 
  {% if variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}- Sold Out{%endif%}
  </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Handling a select change is way better than handling an option click, but this question is primarily about getting the image url from the <option> and your answer doesn't do that. It's getting the variant ID instead.

Comment: @Chris G it does exactly that. if you look at the updated HTML, I changed the value of the option element to the image URL. OP can continue to use the data-* attribute as well and keep the value attribute the way it was.

Comment: True, I didn't see that, but that's a shopify template that will rely on the value being the id, not some image url. Again, this is *specifically* about getting the `data-src` attribute's value; my example code, which works fine for me, doesn't even work for the OP for some reason. Changing around the source HTML is 100% counterproductive here.

Comment: "What i want to make is that when i choose a variant, the featured image also changes to the featured image of that selected variant, but i don't know how should I get its attribute."  OP knows how to get the attribute, he uses $().attr() in his original code. OP wants an event handler tied to the select element, not a click handler on a button that reads the state. Agree to disagree I guess!

Comment: Again, handling the select onchange instead is perfectly fine and preferable to a click handler for each option. That's not my point. My point is that OP is reading the wrong attribute, and instead of fixing their jQuery code you've changed their HTML. This is pointless and probably introduces additional issues. Part of the answer is OP simply changing `var main_img = $(this).attr('data-variant');` to `var main_img = $(this).attr('data-src');` (the *only* issue in their code), but given their comments, this still won't work for them for some yet unknown reason.